# What are Control classes, Entity Classes and Boundary Classes in UML?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

In the class diagram, there are model classes as **Control classes**, **Entity Classes**, and **Boundary Classes**. I try to find a good definition for them, [I found this site](http://web.nchu.edu.tw/~jlu/classes/ooad/CLASS.HTM#:~:text=Boundary%20classes%3A%20A%20boundary%20class,examined%20to%20discover%20boundary%20classes.&text=a%20specific%20entity%20class).,%22executing%22%20the%20use%20case.)  but it isn't that much clear for me.

Comment: Google for MVC to find more appropriate answers.

Comment: There is a very good source for this:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-control-boundary -  If you still have questions after having read it, let me know and I'll answer

Comment: @Christophe Yes. I just intended to urge the OP using Google a bit more in depth....